# Does Sitecore have support for Sitecore products in containers?

Tags: docker, container

I know that Sitecore has a repository for Docker images (https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-images) but as far as I understand currently the code and examples found in this repository are created and maintained by the Community, unsupported by Sitecore and to be used for example purposes only and without official support.

My question is if Sitecore have support for Sitecore products in these containers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While currently Sitecore cannot provide guidance on how to develop or host them in a containerized environment other than those examples, but **if you are hosting a Sitecore solution within a containerized environment, the Sitecore Support team will assist you with any Sitecore product issues**.

More details in this KB article: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/161310